# При открытии экранной клавиатуры фон сжимается. Как этого избежать?

Tags: xml, android, eclipse

Есть `ScrollView` с параметром `background` в виде изображения, в `ScrollView` есть некий контент, включая `EditText`. При выползании экранной клавиатуры фон сжимается по вертикали. Как сделать, чтобы фон оставался неизменным?

Код:

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bkground" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
        //неважно
        />

        <EditText
        //неважно 
        />

        <TextView 
        //неважно
        />

        <Button
        //неважно
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сработало при таком варианте:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bkground" >
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: тогда зачем тут скрол вообще? если у них одинаковые параметы размеров леяутов? он лишний получается..

Comment: Чтобы при компановке можно было пользоваться возможностями RelativeLayout, а при выползании экранной клавиатуры был доступен скролл(ведь клава пол экрана занимает)

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` внутрь вставь, в `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Я ж тогда не смогу пользоваться параметрами, характерными для RelativeLayout, например для кнопки не будет читаться android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Answer (score -1):

Добавь в манифесте в в параметры активити строчку

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?